# Only allow traffic from a GCP load balancer to a VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am new to GCP and have set up a simple VM with a program listening on `port:4000`.
I also set up an external HTTPS load balancer connected to a domain with an SSL cert.
The load balancer routes traffic to the backend service on `port:4000` of the VM and everything works fine.

The issue is that I want to restrict access to port `4000` on the VM so it would only accept traffic from the load balancer and not have it completely open, as it is now.

I changed the firewall rule filter from `0.0.0.0/0` to `35.208.137.235` which is the frontend IP of the load balancer.

But now the VM doesn't accept ingress traffic at all. how should I set it up to only accept traffic from the load balancer?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: The load balancer front end is not making connections to your VM service. That is why your VPC Firewall rule does not work. It allows the wrong traffic. There are multiple types of Google load balancers. That determines which CIDR blocks to allow. There are additional CIDR blocks to allow for **Health Checks**. See the answer and link in Guillaume's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow these ranges `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` as "ingress" rule. It should work.
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/firewall-rules

Comment: Thank you! this led me to find the solution which I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Guillaume I found the answer, although the ranges `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` are for health checks not for traffic between the load balancer and the VM.

The answer is that I am using a regional load balancer and it uses a specific proxy subnet to handle the traffic between the LB and the VM.

the solution I found [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-reg-ext-https-lb?_gl=1*190ec8p*_ga*MTU2OTMzNDE0NS4xNzA2ODExMjg0*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTcwOTkxMjk2MC4yNy4xLjE3MDk5MjA3NzAuMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.151626873.-1569334145.1706811284&_gac=1.229613038.1706811310.Cj0KCQiAn-2tBhDVARIsAGmStVnfiel_0fsFqU-6DvDGa-kJn9ZK6TGjfuRGws85VwOsCsbacIg3bikaAt0nEALw_wcB) after following Guillaume's link.